# When it is possible to delete a question with answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

When attempting to delete own answered question, this message pops up:

> **Delete this answered question?**
>
> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account
>   being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

If you still decide to press delete this message can appear:

> Sorry, this question has answers and can not be deleted. Flag it for
>   moderator attention instead.

When questions with answers can exactly be deleted? I was able to remove one of my "answered" questions yesterday, but it is apparently no longer possibly.
I only delete weak questions with false, low-effort answers.